# How to access the data in a Dropdown list which is inside a repeater when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list inside a repeater which has data in its list item I need to access the selected data when the button inside the repeater is clicked. my html code is as follows

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrData"  OnItemCommand="rptrData_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgress" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No Basement</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Basement</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Lintel</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Roof</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                    <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" UseSubmitBehavior="False" CommandName="Update" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindControl` on the `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` Item since the Repeater is the sender.

```
protected void rptrData_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //use findcontrol to locate the DDL and cast it
    DropDownList drp = e.Item.FindControl("ddlProgress") as DropDownList;

    //show result
    Label1.Text = drp.SelectedValue;
}
```

Note that all your values in `ddlProgress` are `0`, that can cause problems. Make those unique.